# Widgets within a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to add a `QgraphicsView(QColorDialog)` widget onto a `Palette` dialog, but the `QGraphicsScene` corresponding to the `QColorDialog` widget is always blank and it would be of great help if readers could help me correct my mistake.

Qt-4.8.4-Linux(CentOS)

1. The `GraphicsView` widget which will be included in the `PalletteDialog`

   ```
   ClrWidget::ClrWidget(QWidget *parent) :
     QGraphicsView(parent)
   {
     setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
     setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
     setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);

     setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));

     _dialog = new QColorDialog();
     _dialog->setOption(QColorDialog::NoButtons, true);
     setMinimumSize(_dialog->size());
     setMaximumSize(_dialog->size());

     QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
     proxyWidget->setWidget(_dialog);
     //scene()->addItem(proxyWidget);
     //scene()->setSceneRect(proxyWidget->geometry());

     scene()->addWidget(_dialog);
     scene()->setSceneRect(_dialog->geometry());
   }
   ```
2. `PaletteDialog` Constructor

   ```
   PaletteDialog::PaletteDialog(QWidget *parent)
     : QDialog(parent),
     ui(new Ui::PaletteDialog),
   {
     //PaletteDialog sets up the ClrWidget
     ui->setupUi(this);
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: @Jerry_Coffin, you add the _dialog widget to the scene, but where do you set the position of the widget (in the scene) when it has been added? Also, in the past, I've found that there have been problems using QGraphicsProxyWidget with some widgets. Try adding a QGraphicsRectItem to the scene and see if that is displayed where you are expecting the proxy widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
setScene(new QGraphicsScene);
QColorDialog *_dialog = new QColorDialog();
_dialog->setOption(QColorDialog::NoButtons, true);
_dialog->show();
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = scene()->addWidget(_dialog);
```

And remove this line:

`proxyWidget->setWidget(_dialog);`

What you did wrong was set a widget to a QGraphicsProxyWidget and then called [QGraphicsScene::addWidget(..)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) which does the same thing, and that doesn't work. You can add your QGraphicsProxyWidget to the scene though by calling [QGraphicsScene::addItem()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#addItem).

Example:

```
setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
QColorDialog *_dialog = new QColorDialog;
_dialog->setOption(QColorDialog::NoButtons, true);
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = new QGraphicsProxyWidget;
proxyWidget->setWidget(_dialog);
scene()->addItem(proxyWidget);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not help. Another query: When ClrWidget is constructed a modal dialog with the title "Select Color" pops-up and I'm not sure if this is causing the Qgraphics scene to be blank

Comment: @rahul That is strange.. it does work for me.. i modified my answer a little bit and explained what you did wrong. Calling show() on your QColorDialog before adding it to the scene should fix your "Select Color" dialog popping up.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a `QGraphicsScene`, I usually add all of the widgets to the scene before calling `QGraphicsView::setScene(scene)`.  You can remove the call to `scene()->setSceneRect()` in this case because it will automatically be defined by the geometry of the widgets that it contains.  The modified code would look like this:

```
ClrWidget::ClrWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);

QGraphicsScene *scene=new QGraphicsScene((QRect)geometry,this);
_dialog = new QColorDialog();
_dialog->setOption(QColorDialog::NoButtons, true);

//here you should call setGeometry unless it is called in the constructor
 _dialog->setGeometry(rect);
//

setMinimumSize(_dialog->size());
setMaximumSize(_dialog->size());

QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxyWidget = scene->addWidget(_dialog);

setScene(scene);
}
```

Comment: I hope you realize that in this example the scene will get destroyed as soon as the constructor function has finished. So you will need to use QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;

Comment: @buster adding GraphicsWidgets / Items to the scene can be done after setting the scene to the view without any issues.

Comment: @Merlin069 agreed.  I put it last as illustration that `setSceneRect()` does not have to be called.  In the original code, it is called with the geometry of `_dialog`, which could be `QRect(0,0,0,0)`... hence, nothing will display.